Memory issues in scrna_seq pseudobulk aggregation (for muscat Differential State Analysis)
I am new to working with scRNA-seq datasets and I keep running into memory issues when trying to perform differential expression analysis on my data. I know some memory trouble is to be expected with large single-cell datasets but in this specific instance I feel like the problem lies somewhere else.
I am attempting to run differential state analysis based on sex, using this workflow outlines by muscat. The Seurat object I'm working with is fairly large (5.5 GB), so I am using a HPC. Once converted to a SingleCellExperiment object and prepared for DS analysis, it looks like this (so you can get an idea of the size):
class: SingleCellExperiment
dim: 27957 584944 
metadata(1): experiment_info  assays(1): counts
rownames(27957): ENSG00000000003 ENSG00000000005 ... ENSG00000283118   ENSG00000283125 
rowData names(0): 
colnames(584944): GCGACCATCCCTAACC_SC22 P2_1_GCGCAACCAGTTAACC ...   CGATGGCAGCAGGCTA-1-2 AATCGGTGTCGGCACT-1-4 
colData names(3): cluster_id sample_id group_id
reducedDimNames(2): SCANVI_EMB UMAP 
mainExpName: RNA 
altExpNames(0):

Requesting a few tens of GB is enough to load the object and do pre-processing on it. The pseudobulk aggregation function I am using looks like this:
pb <- aggregateData(sce,
                    assay = "counts", fun = "sum",
                   by = c("cluster_id", "sample_id"))

This function triggers an out-of-memory kill event even when I request huge amounts of memory from the cluster I'm working on. I have tried it with something like 800 GB, I have also tried parallelizing the aggregation function with BiocParallel (I've tried a different number of workers here, from 4 to 8 and even 10, each with something like 100 GB allocated to them). I have also tried running the analysis on different levels of annotation of the data to see if the finest annotation level was too ambitious of a task, but even at the coarsest level I run into the same issue. At this point, it seems like the function requires more than a TB of data to run, which just seems ridiculous. I think I'm most likely doing something wrong here.
Is running DS analysis on the entire dataset not the usual way to go? Am I supposed to split it into chunks to run? I can't find anyone posting about memory issues with muscat online. Is there another glaring error I'm omitting?
Thank you in advance for your patience and help!

Can you please show a bit more of your dataset, e.g. the first 10 values of the cluster_id and sample_id fields? In Seurat, this would be done by head(sce$sample_id, 10)
